# How to implement a stack exchange style voting for mobile?

Tags: gui-design

I have a client who wants me to improve the usability of their current iOS app.. they have a voting mechanism that looks like this:

[image]

i figured that this was bad usability b/c it didn't add up the votes to a final number (like how it's done on stack exchange).. and so I created a design that's very similar to the stack exchange voting style:

[image]

he said that he hated my design! he said he didn't like my idea of a vote up vote down.. he couldn't think of another way though..

so any suggestions here folks? any sample implementations of this idea on some famous android or iphone apps?

Comment: my bad.. i took away the rest of my design and focused on just the concept of a vote up down for a mobile device.. i hope that makes my question more generic..

Comment: "he said that he hated my design!" Unfortunately, there's nothing inherently wrong with your design except that the client didn't like it. In this case the "best" answer is really the one that correctly guesses the mindset of the client. I don't know how to help you there; maybe the best approach would be to get some more specific feedback from the client?

Comment: well this ux business is an interesting world.. i'm a developer by trade.. but I also do/read about a lot of ux/ui stuff.. as much as I would like to look at it as a systematic thing.. at the end of the day a client not liking something trumps everything else.. and yes I've seen that happen at amazon too when I used to work there..

Comment: Tough luck with the client, this isn't very constructive though...

Comment: @David it probably isn't, but instead of just down voting me, you can probably also tell us how to make it more constructive? this is my first post on this forum.. and so I'm not sure what parameters or what expectations there are here to make ux questions more generic and constructive.. you can visit my stack over flow [account](http://stackoverflow.com/users/766570/abbood) and you'll see that I'm more than glad to follow protocol and to help the community the best I can

Comment: @David you are right about that having this whole discussion ultimately based on my client's whim isn't a very constructive one.. but as my [answer](http://ux.stackexchange.com/a/36101/28265) and Vincent's [answer](http://ux.stackexchange.com/a/36105/28265) suggest.. this discussion is evolving and becoming more systematic and based on UX philosophy/principles. on my end. i'll try to defend my work before you guys based on those principles. and to try to convince my client that those principles matter and ultimately should make them like the design. I guess that's the best I could do isn't it?

Comment: to @David and everyone else here.. is there an equivalent to this [post](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx) on this forum? like an article that describes what makes a good question on this forum?

Comment: Does he hate it because of lack of thumbs, or because the count of votes shows that it's received a lot of votes both ways, which the total alone doesn't show?

Comment: he hated it b/c in his own words "it's very ugly".. it as his gut reaction to it I guess..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is one of my attempts so far.. basically the item that's voted for comes in the center.. i guess this has better affordance than the previous one.

[image]

**update:**
I convinced my client to go with this one.. I will have to animate into the screen though.

Comment: +1 It's a nice compromise between your design and what your client clearly likes. I'd be interested in hearing how he/she takes the suggestion.

Comment: will let you know as soon as they get back to me.. I'll ultimately put the design that they 'like'.. i guess that's the only criteria for a correct answer here? lol

Comment: Your answer got me thinking and lead to this question: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/36104/should-you-optimize-mobile-experiences-based-on-handedness

Comment: lol just saw it.. i commented on it as well..

Comment: So... where does the result of the vote go? In the middle with a single number? Do you allow to split the result just like you can on StackExchange?

Answer (score 1):

I would definitely go for [your own answer](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/36101/12741) (thumbs-up and thumbs-down control + current count in the center). But if you really need to do things differently you could just show a number and allow a swipe-up to up-vote and a swipe-down for a down-vote.

However, you need to address two problems:

1. This concept **lacks affordance**. At the very least you need to explain how to control this number the first time they see it (perhaps by a swiping animation).
2. You need a **fall-back for non-touch devices**.